# How can stop rss parser after fixed numbers of items?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, rss

I have one rss parser and i want stop him after a fixed number of items, like 5 or 10.
I can put a condition for didn't add more objects in arrat, but parser still continues working and taking memory. 
Can someone help me? Thank you!

```
 - (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL
{

    //you must then convert the path to a proper NSURL or it won't work
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

    // here, for some reason you have to use NSClassFromString when trying to alloc NSXMLParser, otherwise you will get an object not found error
    // this may be necessary only for the toolchain
    rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];

    // Set self as the delegate of the parser so that it will receive the parser delegate methods callbacks.
    [rssParser setDelegate:self];

    // Depending on the XML document you're parsing, you may want to enable these features of NSXMLParser.
    [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

    [rssParser parse];

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{


    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];



    }if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure"]){
        NSString *imageStr = [NSString stringWithString:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
        [item setObject:imageStr forKey:@"_url"];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"]) {
        [item setObject:currentPhoto forKey:@"_url"];}

}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    //NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:currentLink forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"description"];
        [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"pubDate"];
        [item setObject:currentLogo forKey:@"logo"];


        if (itemCount<5) {

        [storiesNationale addObject:[item copy]];
        itemCount++;
    }
        NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentTitle);


    }
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    //NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
    // save the characters for the current item...
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [currentTitle appendString:string];

    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [currentLink appendString:string];

    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        [currentSummary appendString:string];

    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [currentDate appendString:string];
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `abortParsing` method to stop parsing.

```
if (itemCount >= 10)
{
   [parser abortParsing];
   parset.delegate = nil; 
}
else 
{
  itemCount++;
}
```